# Additional GET request on HTTP 303 in Chrome

Tags: ajax, google-chrome, firefox, networking, browser

I am requesting mock server with redirect response (HTTP 303)

When I am checking network in Google Chrome (v66.0.3359.170), I can see one additional GET request compared to Firefox (v60.0 Ubuntu)

Request

```
req.open("POST", "http://localhost:9001/rederict", true);
req.send();
```

Response for http://localhost:9001/rederict

```
HTTP/1.1 303 See Other
Location: http://localhost:9001/response 
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

Response for http://localhost:9001/response

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
{ "Random": "content" }
```

Firefox network

[image: Firefox network]

Chrome network

[image: Chrome network]

Is there any reason why chrome requests one additional GET? (the same situation apply if in request I am using GET instead of POST)